# Using multiple Filters in Query

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

Is there a way to add multiple filters to a query based on a condition to the Query Expression.

For eg something along the lines of.

```
AddressFluentHelper queryHelper=service.getAllAddress;
if(zipCode!=null){
   queryHelper.filter(Address.ZIPCODE.eq(zipCode))
}
if(street!=null){
   queryHelper.filter(Address.STREET.eq(street))
}
```

If this is allowed is the default condition 'AND' between the different filters?
If the default is 'AND' how do we achieve the use case of 'OR'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior is an 'AND' connection between all given `FilterExpression`.

To make this more explicit as well as allowing an 'OR' connection you might consider building the `FilterExpression` "externally", e.g. like this:

```java
import io.vavr.collection.List;
...
List<ExpressionFluentHelper<YOUR_ENTITY>> expressions = List.empty();
if (zipCode != null) {
    expressions = expressions.append(Address.ZIPCODE.eq(zipCode););
}
if (street != null) {
    expressions = expressions.append(Address.STREET.eq(street));
}

AddressFluentHelper queryHelper = service.getAllAddress();
if (!expressions.isEmpty()) {
    // this combines all elements in the "expressions" via "or", starting from the left/the first entry 
    ExpressionFluentHelper<YOUR_ENTITY> combinedExpression = expressions.reduceLeft(ExpressionFluentHelper::or);
    queryHelper.filter(combinedExpression);
}
```